# How to compute a complex function in a cleverer way with Fortran?

Tags: fortran, numerical-methods, complex-numbers

I want to solve this equation by using Fortran:

[image: eq1]

Where ψ (`psi`) is a complex Fortran variable.
Now, I am solving this by defining two new complex variables: 
`ir=(1.0,0.0)` and `ii=(0.0,1.0)`.
I use these to select only the real or imaginary part of the equation. In this way I solve my equation separately for the real and imaginary part. The code is here:

```
do i = 1,nn    
  mod2 = (abs(psi(i)))**2
  psi(i) = ir*(-beta*imag(der2(i)) + alpha*mod2*imag(psi(i))) + ii*(beta*real(der2(i)) - alpha*mod2*real(psi(i)))
end do
```

Where `psi` and `der2` are complex arrays with `nn` elements.
I want to solve this equation in a better way without splitting it in two equations. I tried to solve it in this way:

```
mod2 = abs(psi)**2
psi = -ii*(-beta*der2+alpha*mod2*psi)
```

but it doesn't work because I obtain completely different values with respect to the first method I used. For me it makes sense that it doesn't work because in the second method I am not evaluating the real part. Is this right?
As an example, the 10° element of my psi array becomes:\

1. (-6.39094355774850412E-003,-6.04041029332164168E-003) (with 1° method)\
2. (-1.75266632213431602E-004,-6.21567692553507290E-003) (2° method)\

Any suggestion?
Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, but I can't read your equation at all - it is unfortunate that Stackoverflow doesn't support Mathjax

Comment: Also it would help us if you explain what you mean by "id doesn't work".

Comment: Dear @IanBush , thank you for your reply. I am sorry, this was my first question here on StackOverflow, so I made some mistakes. I added some details on my question.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou No, I don't think so - think array syntax

Comment: Why do you think the second method is incorrect? I'm too tired to check properly now, but the first method doesn't immediately look like your equation to me, while the second does - Fortran treats complex numbers as first class objects, and so will evaluate the real and imaginary parts. Have you printed out a few values and worked out by hand what the correct answer should be in those cases?

Comment: Isn't `|ψ|^2` a single real number and I argue it should be calculated as `sum( real( psi*conjg(psi) ) )` . From what I understand `abs()` is an elemental function and it will return a vector of magnitudes, instead of the magnitude of the vector. There a single one `|ψ|` for each vector `ψ`.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou Ah, OK. It could be read either way I suppose - I am assuming this is a wavefunction where one would typically be interested in the the square modulus of it at a given point in space, and I'm reading the array index referring to different points in space.

Comment: I know that the first method is correct, because actually I am solving the Non linear schordinger equation, that is a PDE (the right side of my equation is d\psi/dt in truth). I am solving this PDE with Runge Kutta and so the equation I showed in my question is only one of my time steps. The output of my simulation with the first method is right. On the contrary, with the second method I obtain NaN after some repetitions of RK (so I suppose my solution grows with time in this case -> It doesn't work).

Comment: @StrizzenSuperfluid - I was not able to replicate your issue, or I was able to correct it. Either way I get the same results for both methods.

Comment: `mod2 = abs(psi)**2` causes the problem because `psi` isn't initialized to begin with introducing the `NaN` values etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `mod2 = abs(psi)**2`  should have been `mod2 = abs(dat)**2`

---

But I think that the correct calculation for `mod2` is `sum( real( dat*conjg(dat) ) )`

I get the same result with both methods with some arbitrary data:

```
eq1=
 (-595.000000000000,-120.200000000000)
 (-713.800000000000,-1.40000000000000)
 (-832.600000000000,117.400000000000)
 (-951.400000000000,236.200000000000)
 (-1070.20000000000,355.000000000000)
 (-1189.00000000000,473.800000000000)
 (-1307.80000000000,592.600000000000)
 (-1426.60000000000,711.400000000000)
 (-1545.40000000000,830.200000000000)
 (-1664.20000000000,949.000000000000)
 eq2=
 (-595.000000000000,-120.200000000000)
 (-713.800000000000,-1.40000000000000)
 (-832.600000000000,117.400000000000)
 (-951.400000000000,236.200000000000)
 (-1070.20000000000,355.000000000000)
 (-1189.00000000000,473.800000000000)
 (-1307.80000000000,592.600000000000)
 (-1426.60000000000,711.400000000000)
 (-1545.40000000000,830.200000000000)
 (-1664.20000000000,949.000000000000)
```

Test code

```
program Console1
use,intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env
implicit none
! Variables
integer, parameter :: sp=real32, wp=real64
complex(wp), parameter :: ir = (1d0,0d0), ii = (0d0,1d0)
real(wp), parameter :: alpha = 0.1d0, beta = 0.2d0
integer, parameter :: n=10
complex(wp) :: dat(n), psi(n), der2(n)
integer :: i

! Body of Console1
    
    dat = [ ( (2d0-i)*ir - (4d0+i)*ii, i=1,n ) ]
    der2 = [ ( -(5d0+i)*ir + (1d0-i)*ii, i=1,n ) ]

    psi = eq1(dat, der2)
    
    print *, "eq1="
    do i=1,n
    print *, psi(i)
    end do

    psi = eq2(dat, der2)
    
    print *, "eq2="
    do i=1,n
    print *, psi(i)
    end do
    

contains

function eq1(dat, der2) result(psi)
complex(wp), intent(in) :: dat(:), der2(size(psi))
complex(wp) :: psi(size(dat))
real(wp) :: mod2        
integer :: i
    mod2 = sum( real( dat*conjg(dat) ) )
    do i=1, size(psi)
        psi(i) = ir*(-beta*imag(der2(i)) + alpha*mod2*imag(dat(i))) + ii*(beta*real(der2(i)) - alpha*mod2*real(dat(i)))
    end do
end function

function eq2(dat, der2) result(psi)
complex(wp), intent(in) :: dat(:), der2(size(dat))
complex(wp) :: psi(size(dat))
real(wp) :: mod2        
    mod2 = sum( real( dat*conjg(dat) ) )
    psi = -ii*(-beta*der2+alpha*mod2*dat)    
end function

end program Console1
```

Also with your definition of `|ψ|` we have also consistent results.

```
eq1=
 (-13.0000000000000,-3.80000000000000)
 (-21.4000000000000,-1.40000000000000)
 (-34.6000000000000,3.40000000000000)
 (-53.8000000000000,11.8000000000000)
 (-80.2000000000000,25.0000000000000)
 (-115.000000000000,44.2000000000000)
 (-159.400000000000,70.6000000000000)
 (-214.600000000000,105.400000000000)
 (-281.800000000000,149.800000000000)
 (-362.200000000000,205.000000000000)
 eq2=
 (-13.0000000000000,-3.80000000000000)
 (-21.4000000000000,-1.40000000000000)
 (-34.6000000000000,3.40000000000000)
 (-53.8000000000000,11.8000000000000)
 (-80.2000000000000,25.0000000000000)
 (-115.000000000000,44.2000000000000)
 (-159.400000000000,70.6000000000000)
 (-214.600000000000,105.400000000000)
 (-281.800000000000,149.800000000000)
 (-362.200000000000,205.000000000000)
```

with code

```
function eq1(dat, der2) result(psi)
complex(wp), intent(in) :: dat(:), der2(size(psi))
complex(wp) :: psi(size(dat))
real(wp) :: mod2(size(dat))
integer :: i
    mod2 = abs(dat)**2 
    do i=1, size(psi)
        psi(i) = ir*(-beta*imag(der2(i)) + alpha*mod2(i)*imag(dat(i))) + ii*(beta*real(der2(i)) - alpha*mod2(i)*real(dat(i)))
    end do
end function

function eq2(dat, der2) result(psi)
complex(wp), intent(in) :: dat(:), der2(size(dat))
complex(wp) :: psi(size(dat))
real(wp) :: mod2(size(dat))     
    mod2 = abs(dat)**2 
    psi = -ii*(-beta*der2+alpha*mod2*dat)    
end function
```

---

Going back to the original problem, I can replicate the issue

```
 eq1=
 (-13.0000000000000,-3.80000000000000)
 (-21.4000000000000,-1.40000000000000)
 (-34.6000000000000,3.40000000000000)
 (-53.8000000000000,11.8000000000000)
 (-80.2000000000000,25.0000000000000)
 (-115.000000000000,44.2000000000000)
 (-159.400000000000,70.6000000000000)
 (-214.600000000000,105.400000000000)
 (-281.800000000000,149.800000000000)
 (-362.200000000000,205.000000000000)
 eq2=
 (0.000000000000000E+000,-1.20000000000000)
 (0.200000000000000,-1.40000000000000)
 (0.400000000000000,-1.60000000000000)
 (0.600000000000000,-1.80000000000000)
 (0.800000000000000,-2.00000000000000)
 (-1952.64000000000,779.256000000000)
 (NaN,NaN)
 (1.40000000000000,-2.60000000000000)
 (NaN,NaN)
 (1.80000000000000,-3.00000000000000)
```

with `mod2 = abs(psi)**2` instead of `mod2 = abs(dat)**2`